# Is it possible to catch an exception you can't handle (in C#)?

Tags: c#, generics, error-handling

I have a generic class that catches exceptions of T:

```
    public abstract class ErrorHandlingOperationInterceptor<T> : OperationInterceptor where T : ApiException
    {
        private readonly Func<OperationResult> _resultFactory;

        protected ErrorHandlingOperationInterceptor(Func<OperationResult> resultFactory)
        {
            _resultFactory = resultFactory;
        }

        public override Func<IEnumerable<OutputMember>> RewriteOperation(Func<IEnumerable<OutputMember>> operationBuilder)
        {
            return () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    return operationBuilder();
                }
                catch (T ex)
                {
                    var operationResult = _resultFactory();
                    operationResult.ResponseResource = new ApiErrorResource { Exception = ex };
                    return operationResult.AsOutput();
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

With subclasses for specific exceptions e.g.

```
    public class BadRequestOperationInterceptor : ErrorHandlingOperationInterceptor<BadRequestException>
    {
        public BadRequestOperationInterceptor() : base(() => new OperationResult.BadRequest()) { }
    }
```

This all seems to work perfectly. But, somehow, in the logs (once, not every time) is an InvalidCastException:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'ErrorHandling.Exceptions.ApiException' to type 'ErrorHandling.Exceptions.UnexpectedInternalServerErrorException'.
   at OperationModel.Interceptors.ErrorHandlingOperationInterceptor`1.c__DisplayClass2.b__1() in c:\BuildAgent\work\da77ba20595a9d4\src\OperationModel\Interceptors\ErrorHandlingOperationInterceptor.cs:line 28
```

Line 28 is the catch.

What am I missing? Have I done something really dumb?

Comment: Is it because the exception that is being fired is not a type of ApiErrorResource? What type is ex when caught?

Comment: Well, there's always `TruthException`, because you can't handle it

Comment: Which line in the code is line 28?

Comment: @KierenJohnstone, you stole my comment!!

Comment: At runtime, T should be a specific exception. So how can it catch an exception of type T, but then fail to cast it to T?

Comment: Line 28 is: catch (T ex)

Comment: I think maybe because T is a specific exception, but you're trying to cast it across class (not up in the inheritance).
Can you simply catch all execptions and then investigate further? -- Just because operationBuilder() throws an exception of type ApiException, doesn't mean it can't throw other kinds of exceptions.

Comment: The idea was to have nested interceptors, each one only interested in a specific exception. If it couldn't handle it, it would bubble up.

Comment: It would rather help if you actually showed how this class is supposed to be used. Presumably a rather specific context. (what with the shown code not even being 28 lines long)

Comment: As Jack Nicholson once said, "YOU CAN'T HANDLE THE EXCEPTION!"

Answer (score 2):

As smithy said, your `T` is of type `ApiErrorResource`.  You are, some where in your code, attempting to create your `ErrorHandlingOperationInterceptor` with an `Exception` that is NOT derived from `ApiErrorResource`.

```
try
{
// throw Exception of some sort
}
catch (BadRequestException ex)
{
    BadRequestOperationInterceptor broi = new BadRequestOperationInterceptor ();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // this is NOT right
    BadRequestOperationInterceptor broi = new BadRequestOperationInterceptor ();
}
```

Comment: Actually I believe it's type `ApiException`.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question. The type system shouldn't allow the problem I think you're trying to demonstrate - note the generic constraint `where T : ApiException`. The OP's code isn't doing any casting - how can an `InvalidCastException` result?

Comment: The given example here doesn't even call the method that would presumably have the problem, so how exactly would this cause problems?